# jQuery: Run one function after another completes

Tags: jquery

```
$('#tab-featured').tap(function(){
    $('.home-section').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#home-featured').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use the code above to call the `fadeIn()` after the `fadeOut()` completes. The `fadeOut()` works fine. I've run functions after others complete before, but this time it's not working and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

Running jQuery latest from their CDN.

Code:

```
<div id="home-mid" class="column-mid">
    <div id="home-featured" class="home-main home-section">
        <!--- Some Code --->
    </div>

    <div id="home-2" class="home-main home-section">
        <!--- Some Code --->
    </div>

    <div id="home-3" class="home-main home-section">
        <!--- Some Code --->
    </div>

    <div id="home-4" class="home-main home-section">
        <!--- Some Code --->
    </div>

    <div id="home-5" class="home-main home-section">
        <!--- Some Code --->
    </div>

    <div id="home-tabs">
        <div id="tab-featured" class="home-tab"></div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="home-tab"></div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="home-tab"></div>
        <div id="tab-4" class="home-tab"></div>
        <div id="tab-5" class="home-tab"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

Tried it with `hide` instead of `fadeOut` and it worked fine. Not sure why `fadeOut` isn't working.

Comment: The code works fine for me, there must be a problem with the selectors. Or maybe you are not describing the problem properly.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I've checked and double checked and the selectors are fine. If I split the code so both functions are run simultaneously than it's fine. It's operating in a way where there are multiple .home-section and one of them has the ID #home-featured, so it sets all the sections to hidden and then shows the desired one. As I said, it usually works.

Comment: What browser are you having the problem in?

Comment: i'm testing in opera desktop and mobile safari. the code usually works fine in them all as it's not even anything special.

Comment: @CoreyRS Update with your html and the version of jQuery that you're using.

Comment: i tried testing it with an alert as well, and the alert wouldn't even run.

Comment: jQuery does not have the tap event, are you using jQTouch?

Comment: nah, custom plugin. `tap` works fine throughout the application and prevents the 300ms delay `click` causes on iOS.

Comment: "Custom plugin" is not telling me much, you should try with jQTouch http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/ as it sounds like event is not firing when it should. Or simply a browser issue, try other browser and update with results.

Comment: check the update i posted. it fires and works fine when i use `hide` instead of `fadeOut`.

Comment: Exactly why i said it's not firing when it should. Hide and fadeOut events are not the same are they? If one fires, and the other doesn't could be a plugin problem.

Answer (score 5):

The first parameter of to the animation functions is a duration, the callback is the second one:

```
$('.home-section').fadeOut(250, function(){
    $('#home-featured').fadeIn();
});
```

Here's [docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

This could be a bug in `fadeOut()` / `fadeIn()` because your home-featured is also a home-section. Try working around it like this:

```
$('.home-section').fadeOut(function(){
    setTimeout(function () { $('#home-featured').fadeIn(); }, 50);
});
```

Comment: @TigOldBitties Apparently jQuery are not swapping parameters if the first one is of type function. I'm just guessing about this but the source code can be checked.

Comment: As i said, the code as written in the question description works fine for me, must be either a browser problem or a selector problem.

Comment: I tried it with duration before posting the question and it still wasn't working.

Comment: @CoreyRS I have added a possible workaround. Try it out to see if it does the job.

Comment: Your workaround didn't work. Seems to be a `fadeOut` bug, so I've just had to use hide instead. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the duration

```
$('#tab-featured').live('tap',function(event) {
    $('.home-section').fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $('#home-featured').fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

OR

```
$('#tab-featured').live('tap',function(event) {
    $('.home-section').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#home-featured').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: First parameter is optional.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the concept of an optional parameter.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: duration is optional but with the proper duration, we can see the action

Comment: So it's not really an answer to the question, nor does it solve anything.